# Pulling Information from API and printing it on Main StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

I'm having difficulty pushing the collected information from the API into my Main StoryBoard. I have a function that deals with collecting all the pieces of the information that I need and then I store it within an Array of strings, within my view did load function. However, when I try to add it to the table view functions nothing appears. Any tips?

Update: I have attempted making some of my statements optional however I can't seem to understand why it is that when I update/reload my tableView it reads it as nil. Below is an image of the error that I am getting and what is being printed on the console.

[Line of code that error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSwwu.png).

[What the console displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii17c.png)

Comment: I don’t get notified when you make an edit. In future you need to reply to my comment and tag me. I just happened to check at the right time. If your tableView is nil then you either haven’t connected the tableView in your storyboard to the instance in the code, or you’ve created a copy of the viewController without using the storyboard constructor, and it can’t be found. In your storyboard you need to open the assistant and crtl drag from the table view in the storyboard, to the tableView property. If you are doing something in code, then again you need to edit and provide a lot more detail

Answer (score 0):

You have an async networking function that will take some time to execute. The Tableview will load its cells on the initial load of the file.

On the first run, your array will be empty when the tableView loads. You need to tell the tableView to reload once you get your data.

Add the call to reload in your completionHandler like so:

```
fetchClassData { [weak self] (classes2) in
    for classes in classes2 {
        self?.classesOG.append(classes.course_id)
        print(self.classesOG)
    }
    
    self?.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:**
that i've also added `[weak self]` to the start of the handler, as you will want to avoid a retain cycle calling self from inside it

Comment: I've tried implementing that portion of code. However, each time I attempt to run it, it seems that it doesn't recognize the keyword append unless I make the entire statement an optional. ("self.classesOG.append(classes.course_id)"). When I do so I still get the error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". Any other tips or places I could look for advice?

Comment: @Eyoab58 yes the line with append will need to be optional too, as `self` is now marked as weak, to avoid leaking memory by having a class have a strong reference to itself (circular dependency). I've updated the code sample above to use `self?.` to unwrap the optional self (never ever use force unwrapping). Try that and see what happens. If you are getting an error, please update your question to include the error message, the line it happens on, and whats being printed to the console by your console logs

Comment: I have made the necessary changes and I have updated the problem.